# Discord.py Pokemon Bot performance problems

Tags: python, postgresql, automation

I have currently problem with discord bot, what is in Python programming language. This commands loading take so long, and I need help with optimization of this code.

```py
from fractions import Fraction
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import asyncpg
import datetime
from aiohttp import web
import random
import json
import math

class Info(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    with open('./poke/resources/pokemon_list.json') as pokemon_list_file:
        global pokemon_list
        pokemon_list = json.load(pokemon_list_file)

    with open('./poke/resources/natures.json') as natures_file:
        global natures
        natures1 = json.load(natures_file)

    global pokes
    pokes = {}
    for pokesm in pokemon_list['pokemons']:
        name = pokesm['name']
        pokes[name] = {}
        pokes[name]['image_url'] = pokesm['image']
        pokes[name]['hp'] = pokesm['hp']
        pokes[name]['attack'] = pokesm['attack']
        pokes[name]['defense'] = pokesm['defense']
        pokes[name]['special_attack'] = pokesm['special_attack']
        pokes[name]['special_defense'] = pokesm['special_defense']
        pokes[name]['speed'] = pokesm['speed']

    global natures
    natures = {}
    for naturesm in natures1['natures']:
        nature = naturesm['name']
        natures[nature] = {}
        natures[nature]['boost'] = naturesm['boost']
        natures[nature]['remove'] = naturesm['remove']



    @commands.command(name="info", aliases=['i'])
    async def info(self, ctx, poke):
        con = await self.bot.pool.acquire()
        fetch_id = await con.fetchval("SELECT pokes[{0}] FROM users WHERE u_id = {1}".format(poke, ctx.message.author.id))
        name = await con.fetchval("SELECT name FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        hpiv = await con.fetchval("SELECT hpiv FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        atkiv = await con.fetchval("SELECT atkiv FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        defiv = await con.fetchval("SELECT defiv FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        spatkiv = await con.fetchval("SELECT spatkiv FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        spdefiv = await con.fetchval("SELECT spdefiv FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        speediv = await con.fetchval("SELECT speediv FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        hpev = await con.fetchval("SELECT hpev FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        atkev = await con.fetchval("SELECT atkev FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        defev = await con.fetchval("SELECT defev FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        spatkev = await con.fetchval("SELECT spatkev FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        spdefev = await con.fetchval("SELECT spdefev FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        speedev = await con.fetchval("SELECT speedev FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        lvl = await con.fetchval("SELECT lvl FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        exp = await con.fetchval("SELECT exp FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        nature = await con.fetchval("SELECT nature FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))
        ability = await con.fetchval("SELECT ability FROM pokes WHERE id = {0}".format(fetch_id))

        hp_base = pokes[name]['hp']
        atk_base = pokes[name]['attack']
        def_base = pokes[name]['defense']
        spatk_base = pokes[name]['special_attack']
        spdef_base = pokes[name]['special_defense']
        speed_base = pokes[name]['speed']

        hp = math.floor((int((2 * hp_base + hpiv + int(hpev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + lvl + 10)
        self.attack = int((int((2 * atk_base + atkiv + int(atkev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + 5)
        self.defense = int((int((2 * def_base + defiv + int(defev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + 5)
        self.special_attack = int((int((2 * spatk_base + spatkiv + int(spatkev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + 5)
        self.special_defense = int((int((2 * spdef_base + spdefiv + int(spdefev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + 5)
        self.speed = int((int((2 * speed_base + speediv + int(speedev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + 5)

        total = int(hpiv) + int(atkiv) + int(defiv) + int(spatkiv) + int(spdefiv) + int(speediv)

        iv_percentage = 100 * (total/186)

        if natures[nature]['boost'] == "Attack":
            attack_initial = self.attack
            self.attack = int(attack_initial) * 1.1
        elif natures[nature]['boost'] == "Defense":
            defense_initial = self.defense
            self.defense = int(defense_initial) * 1.1
        elif natures[nature]['boost'] == "Special Attack":
            special_attack_initial = self.special_attack
            self.special_attack = int(special_attack_initial) * 1.1
        elif natures[nature]['boost'] == "Special Defense":
            special_defense_initial = self.special_defense
            self.special_defense = int(special_defense_initial) * 1.1
        elif natures[nature]['boost'] == "Speed":
            speed_initial = self.speed
            self.speed = int(speed_initial) * 1.1

        if natures[nature]['remove'] == "Attack":
            attack_initial = self.attack
            self.attack = int(attack_initial) * 0.9
        elif natures[nature]['remove'] == "Defense":
            defense_initial = self.defense
            self.defense = int(defense_initial) * 0.9
        elif natures[nature]['remove'] == "Special Attack":
            special_attack_initial = self.special_attack
            self.special_attack = int(special_attack_initial) * 0.9
        elif natures[nature]['remove'] == "Special Defense":
            special_defense_initial = self.special_defense
            self.special_defense = int(special_defense_initial) * 0.9
        elif natures[nature]['remove'] == "Speed":
            speed_initial = self.speed
            self.speed = int(speed_initial) * 0.9

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Level {0} {1}".format(lvl, name), description="""
**Ability**: {0}
**Exp**: {1}
**Nature**: {2}

**HP**: {3} | {4} IVs | {5} EVs
**Attack**: {6} | {7} IVs | {8} EVs
**Defense**: {9} | {10} IVs | {11} EVs
**Special Attack**: {12} | {13} IVs | {14} EVs
**Special Defense**: {15} | {16} IVs | {17} EVs
**Speed**: {18} | {19} IVs | {20} EVs
**IV %**: {21}""".format(ability, exp, nature, hp, hpiv, hpev, int(self.attack), atkiv, atkev, int(self.defense), defiv, defev, int(self.special_attack), spatkiv, spatkev, int(self.special_defense), spdefiv, spdefev, int(self.speed), speediv, speedev, round(iv_percentage, 2)))
        embed.set_image(url=pokes[name]['image_url'])
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await self.bot.pool.release(con)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Info(bot))
```

Just I can't release beta, when this responses take 20 sec sometimes. I want this respond in max 2 sec.

Comment: Just a hint: Why are you doing almost 20 separate database queries when it could be done with one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly the largest slow-down is that you are getting each individual value on its own. Instead get all information at once:

```
poke_query = """
SELECT
hpiv, atkiv, defiv, spatkiv, spdefiv, speediv, 
hpev, atkev, defev, spatkev, spdefev, speedev,
lvl, exp, nature
FROM pokes
WHERE id = {}"""

poke_info = await con.execute(poke_query.format(fetch_id)).fetchone()
```

Note that the parameters you pass to `str.format` are put into the placeholders in the order you pass them, so e.g. `"{0} {1} {2}".format(1, 2, 3)` is equivalent to `"{} {} {}".format(1, 2, 3)`.

You should be able to access the individual columns with their names (e.g. `poke_info.hpiv`) or like a tuple (e.g. `poke_info[0]`).

In addition, most SQL packages allow using parameters. This prevents [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which you should be vary of, because the user of the bot controls the value of `poke`. I think in your case it would be as easy as

```
poke_query = """
SELECT
hpiv, atkiv, defiv, spatkiv, spdefiv,
speediv, hpev, atkev, defev, speedev,
lvl, exp, nature
FROM pokes
WHERE id = ?"""

poke_info = await con.execute(poke_query, fetch_id).fetchone()
```

For the poke ID it is similarly:

```
fetch_id = await con.fetchval("SELECT pokes[?] FROM users WHERE u_id = ?",
                              poke, ctx.message.author.id)
```

These are assuming you are using [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started), but there are equivalent ways to achieve the same thing in other packages.

For example with [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/index.html) it would be `$1` instead of `?`:

```
poke_query = """
SELECT
hpiv, atkiv, defiv, spatkiv, spdefiv,
speediv, hpev, atkev, defev, speedev,
lvl, exp, nature
FROM pokes
WHERE id = $1"""

poke_info = await con.fetchrow(poke_query, fetch_id)
```

Where each value can be accessed as `poke_info['hpiv']` or `poke_inf[0]`.

---

There is no need for `pokes` and `natures` to be `global` values. The way you currently define them they are class variables and you can access them both with `Info.pokes` and `self.pokes`. Beware that these are initialized at class definition time. So if you change the config files you need to restart the script/bot/interpreter. If you put that code into the constructor `__init__` it would be read everytime a new instance of `Info` is created and `pokes` becomes an attribute so can only be accessed via `self.pokes`.

You can also use dictionary expressions to make this a bit easier.

```
class Info(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        with open('./poke/resources/pokemon_list.json') as pokemon_list_file:
            pokemon_list = json.load(pokemon_list_file)
            self.pokes = {p['name']: {'image_url': p['image'],
                                      'hp': p['hp'],
                                      'attack': p['attack'],
                                      'defense': p['defense'],
                                      'special_attack': p['special_attack'],
                                      'special_defense': p['special_defense'],
                                      'speed': p['speed']}
                          for p in json.load(pokemon_list_file)}

        with open('./poke/resources/natures.json') as natures_file:
            self.natures = {n['name']: {'boost': n['boost'],
                                        'remove': n['remove']}
                            for n in json.load(natures_file)}
```

Things get even easier if you don't care that the inner dictionaries also contain the name (and any additional keys) and that the name of the image url changes:

```
class Info(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        with open('./poke/resources/pokemon_list.json') as pokemon_list_file:
            pokemon_list = json.load(pokemon_list_file)
            self.pokes = {p['name']: p for p in json.load(pokemon_list_file)}

        with open('./poke/resources/natures.json') as natures_file:
            self.natures = {n['name']: n for n in json.load(natures_file)}
```

---

I can't say I completely understand all the calculations of the actual stats from the IVs, EVs and base stats. But try to save each stat as its natural type. If a thing is an `int`, save it as an `int` from the beginning and don't continuously cast it to an `int`. This will not save a lot of runtime but make it a lot easier to read.

Another thing you could to for this is put the calculations into their own functions, which you can give a name and docstring explaining what the function does. It also makes it immediately clear that the actual calculation is the same in all cases.

```
def calc(base, iv, ev, lvl):
    """Calculate the actual stat from the base value, IV, EV and current level."""
    return int((int((2 * base + iv + int(ev / 4)) * lvl) / 100) + 5)

self.attack = calc(atk_base, atk_iv, atk_ev, lvl)
self.defense = calc(def_base, def_iv, def_ev, lvl)
...
```

For the boosts and removes, you can shorten it a bit using a mapping from the name to the internal name and in-place operations:

```
mapping = {"Attack": "attack", "Defense": "defense",
           "Special Attack": "special_attack", "Special Defense": "special_defense"}

nature = self.natures[nature]
self.__dict__[mapping[nature['boost']]] *= 1.1
self.__dict__[mapping[nature['remove']]] *= 0.9
```

Instead of this dict you can also use the fact that there is an easy way to convert from one to the other:

```
def nature_to_attr(name):
    return name.lower().replace(" ", "_")

nature = self.natures[nature]
self.__dict__[nature_to_attr(nature['boost'])] *= 1.1
self.__dict__[nature_to_attr(nature['remove'])] *= 0.9
```

Comment: One note: Asyncpg doesn't have fetchone feature, and when you use fetch, you get result like this:
`[<Record ability=None>, <Record ability=None>]`

Comment: @ks1001 It does have [`fetchrow`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.cursor.Cursor.fetchrow), though, which is what I used in the answer.

Comment: I am not really familiar with `asyncpg`, so you might have to call it slightly differently (obviously I could not test the code). Maybe it is actually `con.cursor(poke_query, fetch_id).fetchrow()` or something similar.

Comment: I'll try to move psycopg2, but only when I can get pool over the Cogs (different files)